# Integer pre-increment error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Atleast in C#, ++int increments the integer by 1 before use of it, and -- before int decrements it.
But I get this confusing error when using this piece of code.

```
++int_name *= 10;
```

I increment the integer with 1 and * with 10, still throws compiler error. Some advise would be nice :)

Comment: What compiler error?

Comment: you can't assign calculation result to a value, it should be at leas a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not valid. Use this one instead:

```
int_name = ++int_name * 10;
```

The compiler error you get is:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

`++int_name` is not a variable but an expression yielding an integer number. How could you possibly assign a new value to a number?

Comment: It's purpose was to define the value of experience in game. Each time space is pressed exp becomes: exp = (++int_name * 10);  Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

`++int_name` produces the value `1` assuming that `int_name` was zero before. `1 *= 10` does not make sense. You cannot modify `1`.

In any case you should split that code into multiple statements. Even if this worked nobody would understand it.

Comment: Thanks for further explainment +1 and cheers to that! Sadly only one right answer mark can be given :/